# How to change selected tab title color in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabs, renderer

I am working on xamarin forms `TabbedPage`. I have to make only selected Tab Title to different color.

This is my code

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:go.Models" 
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="Bite2.ViewsForN.SubsView">
    <!--Tab 1 starts here-->
    <ContentPage Title="Buy Subscriptions">
        <StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
    
    <!--Tab 2 starts here-->
    <ContentPage Title="My Subscriptions">
        <StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
        
    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

In customrender, I am setting tab text color gray. I need Black for selected tab and gray for unselected tab.

```
  protected override void SetTabIconImageSource(Google.Android.Material.Tabs.TabLayout.Tab tab, Drawable icon)
    {
        base.SetTabIconImageSource(tab, icon);
        tab.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.subscriptionsTabLayout);
        var title = tab.CustomView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv);
        title.Text = tab.Text;
        ColorStateList csl = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Gray);
        title.SetTextColor(csl);
    }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: [Create a TabbedPage official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page#create-a-tabbedpage): In addition, TabbedPage defines the following properties:

BarBackgroundColor, of type Color, the background color of the tab bar.
BarTextColor, of type Color, the color of text on the tab bar.
SelectedTabColor, of type Color, the color of the tab when it's selected.
UnselectedTabColor, of type Color, the color of the tab when it's unselected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need Black for selected tab and gray for unselected tab.

You don't need to use CustomRender to achieve this.
You can just use properties `UnselectedTabColor` and `SelectedTabColor` of `TabbedPage` .

Please refer to the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedPageWithNavigationPage;assembly=TabbedPageWithNavigationPage" 
            x:Class="TabbedPageWithNavigationPage.MainPage"
            UnselectedTabColor="Gray"
            SelectedTabColor="Black"
            >
    
</TabbedPage>
```